# OmniThread alternatives for iOS/Android/OSX?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, omnithreadlibrary

Are there any alternatives to OmniThread under iOS/Android/OSX?

It does not need to be as complete as OmniThread, I just need to be able to have thread pools and TFuture<> classes.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Delphi XE7 now implements Future/Parallel/Task in System.Threading.

Comment: What was the downvote for? Did I offend somebody's feelings?

Comment: It could be because it's considered a "shopping list" type question, but in this case it's really about implementing decent threading with Delphi on non-Windows OSes. I've also noticed that questions like this tend to be closed/downvoted if the answer is "no" and makes Delphi look bad, but if the answer is "yes" people seem to have no problem posting a list of options. :-(

Comment: Well, I thought it was a useful question.

Comment: Questions like this tend to get closed as off-topic because, as is stated in the close vote dialog: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.* You can debate whether or not it is right that such questions should be closed, but that's just how it is.

Comment: mmm, when Dimitry shows what he has done so far in Windows with some code example and next asks an expert opinion on the best way how to implement this in Android etc., it is a perfectly good question. I am interested in the answer as well.

Comment: Beyond "yes" and "no" valid answers for question expressed this way there are "start porting" and "convince @gabr to do that". I see neither of such answers as useful, and hence the question isnt useful as well. Downvote was from me, I'm sorry if it offended your feelings.

Comment: @alcalde when I know the answer to shopping lists - I put the answer. But after that I still vote for closing.  To topic starter: OTL is FLOSS - you can make it x - platform for everyone's benefit

Comment: @Arioch'The Easy to say. It probably relies heavily on Windows threading primitives. Since they are richer than available on *nix it's not likely to be an easy port.